# Can Workday EIB outbound export files to Azure Blob?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, workday-api, system-integration

This is more of a system integration question, but I'm wondering if Workday EIB has the capability to export csv's to Azure Blobs (i.e. on a cadence).

Currently, I see that supported delivery methods are: Workday attachment, FTP, HTTP/SSL, FTP/SSL, FTP, Email, Amazon simple storage service

Azure Blob isn't explicitly listed as a supported delivery method, so I'm thinking not?

Answer (score 0):

No, EIB can't do that. You will need to develop something.

With an external integration, you get the Workday data from a RAAS (report-as-a-service) and then use the [Azure BLOB Service REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob) to send your data.

Or you can develop a `Workday Studio Integration` instead to do everything in the Workday tenant.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Blob storage now supports incoming SFTP endpoint, so you should be able to integrate directly from EIB with it now.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/secure-file-transfer-protocol-support